# spring 2d array in RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have request

```
http://localhost:8080/user?card[id]=1&card[info][name]=Test+Tester&card[info][time]=123123
```

or another case

```
http://localhost:8080//user/create?phone=123123&systems[0][id]=system1&systems[0][amount]=100&systems[1][id]=system2&systems[1][amount]=50&.
```

How can I accept those arrays in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to send data of large size in a *Get* request. Use a post request and send the data in JSON format. Spring MVC has support for accepting JSON data in a post request.

Here is an example of Jquery POST

```
$.ajax({"type": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "url": "json/hello.do",
    "data": JSON.stringify({"name": "Ricardo"}),
    "dataType": "json",
    "success": function(resp) {alert(resp.message);}
});
```

and the controller mapping

```
@Controller
public class HelloJSON {
@RequestMapping(value="/json/hello.do")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getRegionSettings(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> obj) {
    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    json.put("message", "Hello " + obj.get("name") + "!");
    return json;
}
}
```

Comment: That is not my request. I need to work with another server, which can give only such kind of requests.